# change arrow direction in Visio at "beginning" shape only

Tags: microsoft-visio

Some of our Visio documentation includes fairly long connectors between shapes.

I want to add an arrow at the **beginning** of an arrow that points **away** from the shape.

But all of the arrow ends seem to point **towards** the shape.

Is there a native way to change the direction of the arrow end?  (Please keep in mind that I'm only talking about one end of the line; I'm not trying to "flip the line" by changing both ends).

Or, lacking that, can I supply custom arrows to Visio to provide the "pointing away from" arrow ends?  Or an add-in?

I've found some old descriptions of adding line-ends manually and seen one partial macro script, but I'm still hoping for something out of the box if possible.

Comment: Seems like there is not elegant solution to this problem

Answer (score -1):

The correct solution to this is custom line-ends. That is exactly what they were designed for.

Comment: Explaining how to use Custom Line Ends would make this a better question.

Comment: For that project I did use Custom Line Ends, but they do not scale with the line the same way the native line endings do.  From my perspective, this is a serious limitation in the product (not as serious as the terribly awkward handling of more than one text block per complex shape, though).

If Visio continues to be offered, my preferred solutions would be:
1) allow native lines to have "points away from origin" option
2) (second best) allow Custom Line Ends to scale the same way that native line ends do.  In other words, do #1.